# The base url is not good with easyadmin

Tags: easyadmin

Good morning,

I have symfony 6 running in docker (localhost:9000=production).

In easyadmin in the menu, when I want to access a

> yield MenuItem::linkToCrud

the base url puts localhost:9000 instead of the domain name of my site: result each link is not good.

How can I solve this problem? THANKS

Answer (score 0):

It's because EasyAdmin asks Symfony to generate the full URL for it. So you need to either configure Symfony to use a specific server URL or you can try the [generateRelativeUrls()](https://symfony.com/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/current/dashboards.html#dashboard-configuration) method on the EasyAdmin.